# AutoFixture Relating Object Properties

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture

I'm writing some unit tests and have come across a piece of code that feels like a code smell.

Essentially I have a Web Api. It receives an incoming request 'SomeRequest':

```
public class SomeRequest
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> RequestedDataIds { get; set; } 
}
```

As part of my test. I need to ensure that all of those 'RequestedDataIds' are valid. I have a method call to another part of the system that returns a collection of valid 'SomeData' objects. The 'SomeData' object contains the Id's to validate against:

```
public class SomeData
{
    public int Id { get; set; } //Id to validate against
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My system under test looks something like this:

```
    public void Execute(RequestA request)
    {
        var validDataIds = _someService.GetValidEntities().Select(x => x.Id).ToList();

        var invalidRequestIds = request.RequestedDataIds.Where(requestedId => !validDataIds.Contains(requestedId));

        if (invalidRequestIds.Any())
        {
            throw new SomeException("Error");
        }

        //Carry on as normal
    }
```

My question is. Is there a best practice or any way at all of having AutoFixture get these two collections to interact with each other so that I can have a test to:

1. Test that an exception is thrown when it has invalid request id's
2. Have all other tests ensure that they are the same so an exception isn't thrown
3. Should AutoFixture even be used for this scenario? I could extract the logic and make it a new dependency for the class. Having to then only test it is called. However, testing the dependencies class itself still raises issues 1 & 2.

This is my current attempt at the problem which works. I just don't like it.

1 - Ensure different id's to throw exception

```
    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        _fixture = new Fixture();

        var request = _fixture.Create<SomeRequest>();
        var dataEnitities = _fixture.CreateMany<SomeData>();

        var maxDataEntityId = dataEnitities.Select(x => x.Id).Max();

        request.RequestedDataIds = new List<int> {maxDataEntityId + 1};

        _someService.GetValidEntities.Returns(dataEnitities);

        //Ensure exception is thrown
    }
```

2 - Ensure same id's to prevent exception

```
    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        _fixture = new Fixture();

        var request = _fixture.Create<SomeRequest>();
        var dataEnitities = _fixture.CreateMany<SomeData>();

        request.RequestedDataIds = dataEnitities.Select(x => x.Id);

        _someService.GetValidEntities.Returns(dataEnitities);

        //Ensure no exception is thrown
    }
```

Note - This code is a huge cut down of the actual implementation. Therefore don't be concerned with how it looks/is implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is a code smell. Your tests are valid but they could be simple.
AutoFixture is great tool, but I don't think you need it in this specific case.

First up, try to keep the Execute() method simple as possible. It is used in more or less in a Presentation/Controller/Api layer so keep it lean as possible. Don't want any fat controllers.

You really only need to call the service method.

```
    public void Execute(RequestA  request)
    {
        _someService.ValidateEntities(request);
    }
```

Notice the method name. It does not return anything.
Your service can be something like:

```
    public interface ISomeService
    {
        void ValidateEntities(RequestA request);
    }
```

The implementation of this would return ValidDataEntities from an underlying data source or service.

```
    var validDataIds = GetValidEntities().Select(x => x.Id);
```

I assume you get a list of entities from some sort of a repository or another service.

Push your logic into more domain/poco objects.

Create a simple POCO class i.e EntityValidator, which accepts your Request and the validDataIds. 
You could just Unit Test this POCO class without having to use AutoFixture or any mocking.

```
public class EntityValidator
{
    public void Validate(IEnumerable<int> validEntityIds, RequestA request)
    {
        var invalidRequestIds = request.RequestedDataIds.Where(requestedId => !validEntityIds.Contains(requestedId));

        if (invalidRequestIds.Any())
        {
            throw new SomeException("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Your Unit Tests will be simple you can use the test framework method i.e .Thorws in NUnit test the exception scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We pretty much do as you've suggested and have validators that are injected into our relevant classes. Each validator then being a concise bit of logic that is tested independently. At least it's confirmation that it's a good approach to doing it.